# time to Initialise or start sensor after power given

Tags: arduino, sensors, microcontroller, c

I am working on a time critical project. I use an optical sensor. I would like to know the initialisation or boot time the sensor after power given which will be in µS. How could I measure that?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics*, but I'm afraid that it is not clear what you are asking. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so it's a good idea to include details of **what you are using**, what you want to achieve, what you tried, what you saw & what you expected to see. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works and work through the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) to edit your question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

First crucial thing to know is what is your sensor - its part number, to be clear. If your sensor is digital, its initialization time is probably given in the datasheet.

If you are using analog one, check datasheet too - settling time might be one of values documented. If you can't find anything in the datasheet, you can perform simple test using oscilloscope:

1. Place sensor in some stable state, ie. looking at uniform surface from a fixed position,
2. Connect the probe to analog output of the sensor and probing ground to sensor's ground,
3. Set oscilloscope to single trigger mode,
4. Power up the sensor.

That way you can observe analog voltage rising from zero to some value, determining its initial settling time.

Comment: +1. The information should be published in the datasheet.